# How do I remove support for nested tables in ckeditor without editing the table plugin?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

How do I remove support for nested tables in ckeditor without editing the table plugin?

At first I thought I could just edit the schema, but it seems like there are no support for removing attributes from the schema, I can only add to it?

I know I can edit the table plugin directly, but I would really like to avoid that, because it gets updated each time ckeditor is released.